# Custom transpose array with 3 levels

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

I have this array:

```
$array = [
    [
        'code' => 'dhl',
        'customer_costs' => [
            22 => '1.000', 
            11 => '3.000',
        ]
    ],
    [
        'code' => 'fedex',
        'customer_costs' => [
            22 => '4.000',
            11 => '6.000',
        ]
    ]
];
```

I need to rebuild it this way:

```
array(2) {
  [22]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "1.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "4.000"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "3.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "6.000"
  }
}
```

My code:

```
 $arr=[];
 foreach ($array as $r=>$v) {
     $number = array_keys($v['customer_costs']);

     foreach ($number as $k) {
         $arr[$k][]=[$v['code'] => $v['customer_costs'][$k]];
         
     }
 }
```

this is result enter code here

[image]

I need to use the deepest level's keys as first level keys and combine the `code` value with the deepest level's value respecting the new grouping.

How to make it so that it would be like in the example?

Comment: Might there be more customer costs than 2?  Your sample data shows that there are always two (`22` an `11`).  Do they always match previous subarrays or might the cost keys differ per array row?  Without understanding the variability, we may make incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was an exercise, there is an array, you need to achieve a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, but you're adding an extra array layer in your second loop. Change

```
$arr[$k][]=[$v['code'] => $v['customer_costs'][$k]];
```

to

```
$arr[$k][$v['code']]=$v['customer_costs'][$k];
```

And you'll get

```
array(2) {
  [22]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "1.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "4.000"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "3.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "6.000"
  }
}
```